# Wireless connection behaves strangely after windows 7 fresh installation

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, internet, network-adapter

Since I installed a fresh installation of Windows 7 Home Premium, my Internet connection behaves very strange when on wireless.

1. It disconnects and reconnect by it self without any notice.
2. It slows down, so much that surfing is almost impossible.

One thing that fixes it for a while is, going to the wireless network connection -> status-> and click diagnose, this restarts the wirelesses connection and become fast again. but then after a while the same again it goes very slow.

I installed Linux for a while, and as expected it worked fine with out any problems.

Before this fresh installation I did now, I had the same Windows 7 edition before and everything worked fine then, so I don't know what is really going on...

My wireless card is Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter

and my Router is a D-Link DIR-655

Comment: Do you use multiple acces points? I have seen this kind of behaviour where the wifi-adapter constantly tries to switch from one to another, resulting in similar behaviour. Have you tried installing older driver versions?

Comment: I only have one router, and finding drivers new or older, has been almost impossible, I don't really know why...

Comment: You have installed the most recent driver for this device right  http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=40&system=5

Comment: Some people seem to have worked this out by disabling 'Bluetooth High Speed' under the advanced tab of the adapter device manager page.Also see the driver page here, older versions are listed http://www.atheros.cz/atheros-wireless-download.php?chipset=40&system=6 (i am assuming you use a 64bit version)

Comment: @Jake I tried installing a driver from that website, and it almost crashed my system, then windows said this driver in not compatible. I disabled the High Speed Bluetooth, I will see if it makes any difference...